# How can I receive an Excel file through POST form, and then open it with pandas? (Python3 aiohttp)

Tags: python, pandas, post, aiohttp

I'm trying to get a file from the user with the following form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/demo" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="file">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Add Excel</button>
</form>
```

In my views.py

When I use `file = post.get("myfile")` and then print it I get the following:

```
FileField(name='myfile', filename='file.xlsx', file=<_io.BufferedRandom name=12>, 
content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 
headers=<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="myfile"; 
filename="file.xlsx"', 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')>)
```

But when I try to create a DataFrame with pandas `df = pandas.read_excel(file, header= None, dtype=str)` I get:

```
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 422, in _handle_request
    resp = await self._request_handler(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 499, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "/Users/ricardonunez/code/OCE/LocalVersion/Service/views.py", line 20, in upload_file
    db.processF(file1)
  File "/Users/ricardonunez/code/OCE/LocalVersion/Service/db.py", line 757, in processF
    df = pandas.read_excel(fr, header= None, dtype=str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1071, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 949, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 558, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 371, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'aiohttp.web_request.FileField'>
```

Am I receiving the file correctly?
How can I create a DataFrame of the file with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file upon receiving it. What you get when you print it is just its memory representation in the web server. More info on handling uploads in Django: [uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)